# How to retrieve specific list of objects from array when changing state in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an array like this.

[image]

I want to get all the actual sizes when selecting a packing name and also when selecting the one of actual size from the list it should be retrieve order size according to each actual size. How can I achieve this?

```
const [packing, setPacking] = useState([])
const [sizes, seSizes] = useState([])
```

**change packing name**

```
const onChangeMaterialName = async (id, setFieldValue) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/packingDetails/${id}`)
    console.log('data', data.sizes)
    setFieldValue('actualSize', data.sizes) //here I want to fix
  }
```

**change actual sizes**

```
  const onChangeMaterialActualSize = (e, setFieldValue, values) => {
    // setFieldValue('orderSize', data.sizes[0]) //I want fix
  }
```

**this is my components**

- set packing name

  ```
                              <Grid
                               item
                               className={classes.flex}
                               md={3}
                               sm={12}
                               xs={12}
                             >
                               <FormControl
                                 fullWidth
                                 variant='outlined'
                                 size='small'
                               >
                                 <Autocomplete
                                   onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                                     if (newValue) {
                                       onChangeMaterialName(
                                         newValue.id,
                                         setFieldValue
                                       )
                                       setFieldValue(
                                         'packingName',
                                         newValue.packingName
                                       )
                                     }
                                   }}
                                   options={packing}
                                   size='small'
                                   getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                                   renderInput={(params) => (
                                     <TextF
                                       {...params}
                                       label='Name'
                                       variant='outlined'
                                     />
                                   )}
                                 />
                               </FormControl>
                             </Grid>
  ```
- set actual Size

  ```
                         <Grid
                           item
                           className={classes.flex}
                           md={3}
                           sm={12}
                           xs={12}
                         >
                           <FormControl
                             fullWidth
                             variant='outlined'
                             size='small'
                           >
                             <InputLabel id='demo-simple-select-label'>
                               Actual Size
                             </InputLabel>
                             <Select
                               size='small'
                               onChange={(e) => {
                                 onChangeMaterialActualSize(
                                   e,
                                   setFieldValue,
                                   values
                                 )
                               }}
                               onBlur={handleBlur}
                               value={values.actualSize}
                               fullWidth
                               labelId='demo-simple-select-outlined-label'
                               id='demo-simple-select-outlined'
                               label='Actual Size'
                               name='actualSize'
                             >
                               {sizes.map((e, i) => (
                                 <MenuItem value={e} key={e.id}>
                                   {e.actualSize}
                                 </MenuItem>
                               ))}
                             </Select>
                           </FormControl>
                         </Grid>
  ```
- Set order size

  ```
                         <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={3}>
                           <Field
                             name='orderSize'
                             size='small'
                             label='Order Size'
                             component={TextField}
                             variant='outlined'
                             disabled
                             fullWidth
                           ></Field>
                         </Grid>
  ```

Comment: what do you mean by getting all the actualsize?
do you want to sum all the actualSize data received for a particular id?

Comment: @RishavPandey   No, not the sum I want to get the value of actual sizes. (ex; list like this   25 25 25 80 )

Answer (score 0):

update `onChangeMaterialActualSize` with -

```
const onChangeMaterialActualSize = (e) => {
 const name = e.target.name; // it'll return 'actualSize'
 const value = e.target.value; //it'll return selected id
 // now you can perform any operation like storing value in state using setState
}
```

and your `Select` component with -

```
<Select
 ...
 name='actualSize'
 onChange={onChangeMaterialActualSize}
 ...
>
 {sizes.map(size => (
 <MenuItem value={size.id} key={size.id}>
  {size.actualSize}
 </MenuItem>
 ))}
</Select>
```

Also, I believe you should store a list of data in a different variables after fetching from API just to render and store the value of input components like `AutoComplete` and `Select` in different variables.